# Is it possible to connect to multiple VPN networks at once via Network Manager?

Tags: networking, vpn

Is it possible to connect more VPN networks at once via Network Manager?

I am running Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS.

For now I am only able to switch between preconfigured VPN connections. It`s quite annoying as I need to be connected to two or more VPN networks simultaneously.

For example on Windows OpenVPN clients, it is possible.

Answer (score 12):

With 12.10 (network-manager 0.9.6), you can connect to multiple VPNs using the network settings:

- System settings (gnome-control-center)
- Network
- Select each VPN and set it to "on".

You can also use the `nmcli` tool; see http://cweiske.de/tagebuch/networkmanager-vpn.htm for more information.

Comment: This causes my first VPN connection get dropped. As @Simon Déziel have mentioned this looks like to be a kind of bug.

Comment: I think this only works if the VPN connections use different providers. e.g. not both Cisco `vpnc` connctions. I've even had cases where VPN using a given provider just broke and refused to reconnect until I rebooted when I tried this.

Answer (score 5):

This is a known limitation of network-manager-openvpn. You can subscribe to https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager-openvpn/+bug/671024 and mark the bug as affecting you.

As mentioned in the first comment, it is possible to connect to multiple VPNs but not via Network Manager.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that what you want is not possible at the moment. There are a lot of bugs on this issue like [this](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager/+bug/91389) and it was assigned to upstream.

Even so, you can connect multiple vpns at once as described in [this](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager/+bug/91389/comments/14) answer. You can write you own configuration file by reading "Manually configuring your connection" section in [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VPNClient) Ubuntu help page.

Answer (score 3):

You can't do it with Network Manager, but yes, using Network Manager and pptp.

Here is how I make it works in my case.

1. Connect to the first VPN using Network Manager.
2. Connect to the second VPN with command `pon vpn2`, use `poff vpn2` to disconect the second VPN.

To make the command `pon` works, you will need to create the followed files in your system:

file `/etc/ppp/peers/vpn2`:

```
pty "pptp VPNIpAddress --nolaunchpppd"
name YourUsername
remotename PPTP
require-mppe-128
file /etc/ppp/options.pptp
ipparam vdc
```

file `/etc/ppp/options.pptp`:

```
lock
noauth
refuse-pap
refuse-eap
refuse-chap
refuse-mschap
nobsdcomp
nodeflate
```

Of course the content of these files is depends on your VPN servers.

In my case I also should to add the ip-up.d/ rules, to add the necessary routes.

file `/etc/ppp/ip-up.d/vpn2`

```
#!/bin/bash
case "$PPP_REMOTE" in
        YourVPNGatewayIPHere)
        route add ....
        route add ....
        ...
                ;;
    *)
esac
```

Don't forget: `sudo chmod +x /etc/ppp/ip-up.d/vpn2`

Also you will need to edit the file `/etc/ppp/chap-secrets` and add there your credentials.

After this, connecting to VPN1 with Network Manager, run:

```
sudo pon vpn2
```

Check syslog if something goes wrong.