# How do I configure NetworkManager to connect to two separate VPN servers simultaneously?

Tags: 13.10, network-manager, vpn, openvpn

I have to connect to two OpenVPN servers at once. How do I configure NetworkManager to connect as a client to both?

```
           -- <OpenVPN1> -- <Resource 1>
<laptop> -
           -- <OpenVPN2> -- <Resource 2>
```

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/190899/is-it-possible-to-connect-to-multiple-vpn-networks-at-once-via-network-manager

Comment: Yes, it looks so.  And the [answer there](http://askubuntu.com/a/243085/162112) worked for me.  Instead of opening the Network Manager, open System Settings -> Network.  Multiple VPNs can be checked ON.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it is impossible using only Network Manager. But you can use a little trick:

First export your OpenVPN2 settings from Network Manager to some file, say `ovpn2.conf`.

Find your OpenVPN1 connection UUID:

```
nmcli con
```

Write script below, and put it under `/etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/`, say `two_vpn`

```
#!/bin/sh
VPN_UUID=84d61cf6-6f51-4f84-93fb-df3c458db6d6
CONF_FILE=path/to/ovpn2.conf

interface=$1 status=$2
case $status in
  up|vpn-up)
      if [ $VPN_UUID == $CONNECTION_UUID ]; then
        # connect your second OpenVPN2 using .conf file:
        openvpn --config $CONF_FILE

      fi
    ;;
  down| vpn-down)
      if [ $VPN_UUID == $CONNECTION_UUID ]; then
        # close your second OpenVPN2
        pid=$(ps -ef | grep "[o]penvpn --config $CONF_FILE" | awk '{ print $2 }')
        kill $pid > /dev/null 2>&1
      fi
    ;;
esac
```

Don't forget to give `chmod +x /etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/two_vpn`

That's it, now you only need to connect OpenVPN1, and OpenVPN2 will connect automatically. Also if you close OpenVPN1, OpenVPN2 will close.

**Please let me know if something goes wrong, because I did not test script**